# how to make horizontal scroll like metro?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need make something similar to Windows 8's Metro style horizontal scrolling.  For example, when the user moves the mouse in corner, the scrollers move with it.

I tried this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    document.documentElement.onmousewheel = function (event) {
        $('body').scrollLeft($('body').scrollLeft() - event.wheelDelta);
    };
});
```

But the horizontal scrolling is not quite working as I'd expect it to.

How should I make a Windows 8 style horizontal scroll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

To get horizontal scrolling the Mouse Wheel Plugin by Brandon Aaron (GitHub, Download) will be used to detect mouse wheel movements like a keypress and of course, jQuery itself will be used.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('html, body, *').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
    this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 40);
    e.preventDefault();
});
})
```

The JavaScript can just be added into the Head tag. Note that scrolling applies to html, body and * (everything) – this enables it to work across different browsers. The event.preventDefault() just disables vertical scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

Check jquery plugin jcarousel:

http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_auto.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try out http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/, supports scrolling both horizontal and vertical and is easy to style and supports different easing transitions.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:
**HTML:**

```
<div class="hScroll">
    <div class="content">
        <!-- your content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hScroll {
    position: relative;
    width: 99999em;
    height: 100%;
}
.content {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.hScroll').width($('.content').outerWidth());
});
document.documentElement.onmousewheel = function (event) {
    $('body').scrollLeft($('body').scrollLeft() - event.wheelDelta);
    event.preventDefault();
};
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/JEX23/

Comment: Thanks, But the horizontal scrolling is not quite working on mousewheel.